# scanned 0 is absent in printf

Tags: c, printf

In the number `scanf()` part of this code, if I enter input 01234567 , the `printf()` function prints 1234567 and it does not print the 0 . What to do to solve the problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long int number , date , month , year ;
    char name[50];

    printf("Enter name \n");
    gets(name);
    printf("Enter mobile number\n");
    scanf("%ld",&number);

    printf("Enter date of birth(date)\n");
    scanf("%ld",&date);

    printf("Enter date of birth(month)\n");
    scanf("%ld",&month);

    printf("Enter date of birth(year)\n");
    scanf("%ld",&year);

    ///printing starts
    printf("Name: %s\n",name);
    printf("Number: %ld\n",number);
    printf("DOB: %ld/%ld/%ld",date,month,year);
    return 0;
}
```

for the number part , 
this code shows the output : 1234567 but input was 01234567

Expected output : 01234567

Comment: Are you considering it as an octal number?

Comment: no , not a 7 digit number , I want to scan 11 digit .

Comment: Please read documentation of [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) and [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). You should use the return count of `scanf`

Comment: regarding: `gets(name);`  the function: `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely removed from the latest versions of C.  Your compiler should have told you this.  Suggest using `fgets()`  (see the MAN page for the details of `fgets()`

Comment: the leading 0 is not a valid part of an integer.  Suggest replacing the field definition with an array of characters and using the '%s' input format specifier in the call to `scanf()`

Comment: OT:  when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions.1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the input format specifiers: '%s' and/or '%[...]' always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input field, because those format specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("Number: %011ld\n",number);
```

This will prefix `0` to make it eleven character as required in  OP. Hence **01234567** will become **00001234567**

Comment: Okay , understood, Thank you.

Comment: Detail: `"%011ld"` does not make it "eleven digit as required".  It makes it "eleven character ...".  `printf("Number: %011ld\n",-1234567);` becomes `"-0001234567"`, a 10 digit output.

Answer (score 2):

There is no real difference between the *numbers* 1, 01, 0000001, 1.0, and so on<sup>(a)</sup>. That's because the number is the *value,* not the *formatting.*

If you want to preserve leading zeros, you should probably be treating it as a string rather than a number.

That's especially true if you're talking about phone numbers (which seems to be the problem case at hand) since they can come in *many* forms that don't comply with a simple integer, such as:

```
0413 198 234
(0407) 123-456
0412 diablo
```

---

You should also be circumspect about `gets()`, there's a reason why it's one of the few things ever to have actually been removed from the standard - there is no safe way to use it. Instead, look into any of the many options that are far safer, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used/4309871#4309871).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> In terms of mathematical quantities, obviously. They may be treated differently in C source code in terms of data type or radix used.

Comment: Okay , Thank you for telling about the gets part, I will look into it . Great Help!

Comment: @rhythm, the most efficient way to thank someone who answers you on Stack Overflow is by accepting his answer by clicking on check mark button, Accept this answer if this solved your problem

Comment: Taking input as a string is one way to solve this issue.  There is no hurry to accept.

Answer (score 1):

To print leading zeros, code can record the length with `"%n"` of the numeric input for subsequent printing.

```
printf("Enter mobile number\n");

int n1 = 0;
int n2 = 0;
//     v------------ consume leading spaces.
//     |vv---vv----- record offset of scan
scanf(" %n%ld%n",&n1, &number, &n2);
//               v--------------- pad with zeros as needed
//               |v-------------- width determined by argument
printf("Number: %0*ld\n", n2-n1, number);
```